# Asynchronous Query JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have been playing around with a module from NPM called JSON-Query, I originally able to make the module function with JSON embedded in my js.

I have spent about two days attempting to make it query JSON that is external and in a JSON file.

The original code that was functioning looked something like this.

```
var jsonQuery = require('json-query')
var data = {
  people: [
    {name: 'Matt', country: 'NZ'},
    {name: 'Pete', country: 'AU'},
    {name: 'Mikey', country: 'NZ'}
  ]
}

jsonQuery('people[country=NZ].name', {
  data: data
}) //=> {value: 'Matt', parents: [...], key: 0} ... etc
```

I was able to query the internal JSON to find the key I was looking for.

I realized I need the ability to update the JSON while the code is live, so I moved the JSON to its own file.

Currently my main JS file looks like this.

```
var jsonQuery = require('json-query');
var fs = require('fs');

function querydb(netdomain){
fs.readFile('./querykeys.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err){console.log('error');} 
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);

    console.log(jsonQuery('servers[netshare=Dacie2015].netdomain', {
          obj: obj
        }));



});
}

querydb();
```

My JSON file that contains the json looks like this.

```
{
          "servers": [
            {"netdomain": "google.com", "netshare": "password", "authip":"216.58.203.46"},
            {"netdomain": "localhost", "netshare": "localghost", "authip":"127.0.0.1"},
            {"netdomain": "facebook.com", "netshare": "timeline", "authip":"31.13.69.228"}
          ]
}
```

The issue I have ran into, I am unable to query the JSON anymore, when the function QueryDB() is ran, no matter what is in the place to query the JSON, i get no response locating my key.

Currently the response I get from the server when i try to query the JSON file is

```
{ value: null,
  key: 'netdomain',
  references: [],
  parents: [ { key: 'servers', value: null }, { key: null, value: null } ] }
```

To be abundantly clear, i believe my issue is the way i call my object into play, i have played with the structure of the JSON-Query and have been unable to accomplish being able to isolate a key.

Any help on this would be amazing, the module that i am working with can be found on npm at [NPM]https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-query

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is just a typo. Shouldn't this:

```
obj: obj
```

be this?

```
data: obj
```

Comment: This Worked! What does this line of code function as? i understand obj comes from the parsing of the JSON, is data: what the function is replying with?

Comment: `data` is the key in the array. `{ data: obj }` means there's an array with `"data"` as the key and `obj` as the value. The function you're calling expects there to be a key called `"data"`, so you need to use it.